# Conflicting types and previous declaration issue

Tags: c, cs50

I ran into a problem compiling my code.

```
error: credit.c:38:6: error: conflicting types for 'check_validity'
bool check_validity(credit_card_number)
     ^
credit.c:8:6: note: previous declaration is here
bool check_validity(long);
     ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
```

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me on this. There are probably a lot of issues with the code so do pardon my novice attempt at it.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int find_num_digits(long);
bool check_validity(long);
bool inspect_length(int);
int main(void)
{
    long credit_card_number;
    // Prompt for input//
    do
    {
        credit_card_number = get_long("Credit card no: ");
    }
    while ( credit_card_number <= 0);
    int num_digits = find_num_digits(credit_card_number);  //Find number of digits in the credit card no//
    bool is_length_card_valid = inspect_length(num_digits);
    bool is_card_valid = check_validity(credit_card_number); //Check the Luhn's Algorithm works with the equations//


}

 bool inspect_length(num_digits)
{
    if (num_digits == 13 || num_digits == 15 || num_digits == 16)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

bool check_validity(credit_card_number)
{
    int total = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    while (credit_card_number != 0)
    {
        if (counter % 2 == 0)
        {

            int num_1 = credit_card_number % 10 * 2 total = total + num_1 % 10 total = total + num_1 / 10
        }

        else if (counter % 2 != 0)
        {
            total = total + credit_card_number %
        }
        counter++;
        credit_card_number / 10;
    }
    if (total % 10 == 0)

    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

int find_num_digits(long card_number)
{
    int digits = 0;
    while (card_number != 0)
    {
        card_number = card_number / 10;
        digits++;
    }
    return digits;
}
```

Comment: Look at how you defined `find_num_digits`, then look at how you defined `inspect_length` and `check_validity`.  Notice a difference?

Comment: There are many issues with this code, but the core issue being asked about is due to essentially a typo. `bool inspect_length(num_digits)` and `bool check_validity(credit_card_number)` do not provide types for their arguments.

Comment: You are writing K&R (non-prototype) function definitions, naming the parameters but not specifying the types.  That means the type is `int` (and not `long`) each time.  Adjust your compiler so that it rejects K&R-style functions.  Do not write K&R-style functions.

Comment: @Velosion What is unclear with the error messages? They were issued specially for you.

Comment: Please don't change your question in a way making comments and answers invalid. You now show a completely different error message. That's a no-go.

Comment: If you have a new question, post it *as* a new question.  Do not modify an existing question to something altogether different, *especially* after receiving an answer.  Rolled back.

Answer (score 2):

The issue comes from this :

```
bool check_validity(credit_card_number)
```

It should be :

```
bool check_validity(long credit_card_number)
```

Comment: oh wait it fixed the issue, may i know why should i include the long? thanks so much btw

Comment: @Velosion because parameters need a type. Check your learning material about function definitions and parameter lists.